# ArgumentException: The given port name does not start with COM/com or does not resolve to a valid serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, argumentexception, virtual-serial-port

I am trying to connect to a virtual com port provided by the drivers of a u-blox GPS device.

The device appears normally under the Sensors tab in Device Manager and I can really get the coordinate data using `GeoCoordinateWatcher` class from C#.

But I want to read the underlying NMEA data.
So in the process of doing that I installed the `Virtual Com Port` driver provided by U-BLOX and it generated a u-blox virta com port in devices manager.

Connecting to that using `Putty` is OK and I can see all the NMEA lines being dumped there.

but when I try to connect to the same port (after `Putty` is closed obviously) using C# I get the exception mentioned in the title

> The given port name does not start with COM/com or does not resolve to
>   a valid serial port

My code is fairly simple (not the first time I use com ports) and everything is correctly defined (Port Name, Stop Bits, Parity, BaudRate etc). I even tried changing to a "wrong" com port name to see the exception I will get and it is completely different (Com Port does not a exit exception).

So what is happening with C# at this point? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in the SerialPort class? Putty seems to work just fine in connecting and streaming the data.
My code is as simple as the following

```
m_port = new SerialPort
{
    PortName = m_portName,
    BaudRate = m_baudRate,
    Parity = m_parityBit,
    DataBits = m_dataBits,
    StopBits = m_stopBit
};

m_port.Open();
```

I even tried hardcoding the values and I still get the same exception.
I tried many of the suggested solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605429/c-sharp-serialportopen-method-throws-argumentexception-because-of-port-name), none of them helped.
I also tried changing the COM port number from Device Manager advanced settings, that also did not help

Comment: Have you tried renaming the COM port and use the new name instead of old one.

Comment: Yes. Forgot to mention that. From advanced settings

Comment: I haven't worked with u-blox..  but I hope the below be useful for you.. https://forum.u-blox.com/index.php/9380/neo-7-serial-port-windows-10-net   .  It seems there are some issues with connecting to serial port as it won't behave like the exact serial port.

Comment: @JSR Well, all they say is that it does not really work

Comment: We use an Ethernet modual called NetBurner.  They have a really nice application for setting up true virtual COM ports.  Maybe give that a try, I have no issues connecting to the VCOMs I made with my C# app.  
 http://www.netburner.com/support/documents/sb70/deployment-tools-9/473-virtual-comm-port-driver-12/file

Comment: @Baddack I decided to use another GPS device instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out U-BLOX virtual COM port driver does not fully emulate a COM port which causes issues with `.Net`. Regardless if it is `C#` or `C++` or any other language running on `.Net` 
The only solution is to either, not use this device, or use an intermediary software.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any particular reason for using the VCP driver, use the CDC driver instead. Available as "u-blox GNSS Standard Driver for Windows" at their website:

https://www.u-blox.com/en/product-resources/2673The/field_file_category/driver-221/field_file_products%253Afield_product_category/position-time-152

I had the same problem as you, but by changing the device driver, everything works as expected. It seems like their VCP driver is not fully compatible with the regular serial port driver structure.

Comment: You might need to reconfigure the ports for the CDC driver. Use the u-center tool to enable NMEA output to USB.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue, and thought I'd share my solution.

I wasn't able to use the CDC driver, as my device is a Rugged Windows Device with a dedicated GPS - the CDC solution may only work for removable gps devices via USB. The sensor driver must be installed, and the VCP driver can be installed alongside the sensor to provide a COM port.

Whilst the VCP driver does not fully emulate a COM port, you can use another piece of software to fully emulate the uBlox virtual com port and fill in the gaps. GPS Gate was that software for me - https://gpsgate.com/. The end result is uBlox Sensor -> uBlox VCP -> GPS Gate VCP. I was then able to successfully use the GPS Gate VCP in my C# app, and have GPS data coming down.

GPS Gate also offers a Location API plugin which could remove the uBlox VCP from the equation (uBlox Sensor -> GPS Gate VCP through Location API), but I didn't have much luck with it, plus I already had a working solution.